# Logstash convert @timestamp to new field with timezone

Tags: logstash

I am trying to convert "@timestamp": "2017-08-16T15:20:07.254Z" to "America/Vancouver" timezone.

This is the output:
"localtimestamp" => "2017-08-16 15:20:07.254",
"localtimestamp1" => 2017-08-16T22:20:07.254Z,

```
  mutate {
        add_field => {
            # Create a new field with string value of the UTC event date
            "localtimestamp" => "%{@timestamp}"
        }
    }
ruby {
    code => "
        event.set('localtimestamp' , event.get('@timestamp').time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L'))
    "
    }
      date {
        match => [ "localtimestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
        timezone => "America/Vancouver"
        target => "localtimestamp1"
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. I just need to show the @timestamp in a new field with the stamp converted to a local time

Comment: This is sort of unusual.  Can you describe why you want another timestamp in another timezone?

Comment: I have a timestamp of a message that is in UTC (default). I would like to get this timestamp, convert to the timestamp of the timezone the message came from, and put it in a new field so that I can match it with a local log (in local timezone) where that message came from. Does that make sense?

Comment: I am just trying to display the timestamp in local timezone where the log came from.